# Using a template parameter to match tag

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to use a template parameter to match a namespaced tag? For example

```
<xsl:template match="abc:tag_name">
  <xsl:param name="tag_to_get" />
  <xsl:if test="abc:{$tag_to_get}"><xsl:value-of select="$tag_to_get" /> tag exists</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Edit:
I want to transpose a table of data stored in an XML document, but not every element has the same children. So I want to iterate over the different possible child nodes, creating a new row in the table and test if each element in the xml doc has a child node as given by the possible child node. So for example, given the following XML:

```
<root>
<foo name="element_a">
  <bar />
</foo>
<foo name="element_b">
  <baz />
</foo>
</root>
```

I want to create

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>child</th>
    <th>element_a</th>
    <th>element_b</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Which elements have bar children -->
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- Which elements have baz children -->
    <td>baz</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So the previous example would become:

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <style> table { border-collapse: collapse; font: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; } table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }</style>
         </head>
         <body>
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>child</th>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/foo"><xsl:with-param name="tag_to_get" select="'headers'" /></xsl:apply-templates>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>bar</td>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/foo"><xsl:with-param name="tag_to_get" select="'bar'" /></xsl:apply-templates>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>baz</td>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/foo"><xsl:with-param name="tag_to_get" select="'baz'" /></xsl:apply-templates>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="foo">
      <xsl:param name="tag_to_get" />
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$tag_to_get = 'headers'">
            <th><xsl:value-of select="./@name" /></th>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <td><!-- <xsl:if test="{$tag_to_get}">X</xsl:if>  --></td>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

But I don't know how to use the parameter to match the element.

Comment: Could you provide a more comprehensive example, including a sample XML input? Also indicate which version of XSLT you are using. -- It seems to me your question is about matching an element using a parameter - not necessarily related to namespaces.

Comment: Correct, I want to match an element using a parameter. I mentioned namespaces because I wasn't sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: It seems that you know in advance both the namespace/s of the input XML and the element names to get. If so, it's not clear to me why don't you just use them directly; the only reason to parametrize them would be if you needed to pass the element names to the stylesheet at runtime.

Comment: I was hoping to simplify the code. If I could use the parameter for matching the child element, then the template for foo would be very similar to the example. Otherwise I would need to have a branch for each child element.

Comment: "*I was hoping to simplify the code.*"  IMHO, you are achieving the opposite. Post a more complex XML input that could be used to demonstrate. -- And we are still waiting to be told which version of XSLT you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **local-name()** function in this instance....

```
 <xsl:if test="*[local-name()=$tag_to_get]">
     <xsl:value-of select="$tag_to_get" /> tag exists
 </xsl:if>
```

**local-name()** returns the name of the element without the namespace prefix.

It might be better having a totally separate template for you header, and distinguishing it with the use of a **mode** attribute.

Try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <html>
         <head/>
         <body>
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>child</th>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="foo" mode="header" />
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>bar</td>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="foo">
                     <xsl:with-param name="tag_to_get" select="'bar'" />
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>baz</td>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="foo">
                     <xsl:with-param name="tag_to_get" select="'baz'" />
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="foo" mode="header">
      <th><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></th>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="foo">
      <xsl:param name="tag_to_get" />
      <td>
         <xsl:if test="*[local-name()=$tag_to_get]">X</xsl:if>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
<body><table>
<tr>
<th>child</th>
<th>element_a</th>
<th>element_b</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>bar</td>
<td>X</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>baz</td>
<td></td>
<td>X</td>
</tr>
</table></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example with the corrected xml. I am looking for multiple **foo** which your solution does not allow for. Also, how does the **foo/header** template match if the **header** element does not exist?

Comment: I finally understand now! I have corrected my XSLT to give you the output you require.